# C++ removing punctuation on strings, erase()/iterator issue

Tags: c++, string, iterator

I know I'm not the first person to bring up the issue with reverse iterators trying to call the erase() method on strings. However, I wasn't able to find any good ways around this.

I'm reading the contents of a file, which contains a bunch of words. When I read in a word, I want to pass it to a function I have called stripPunct. However, I ONLY want to strip punctuation at the beginning and end of a string, not in the middle.

So for instance:

*(word)* should strip '(' and ')' resulting in just *word*

*don't!* should strip '!' resulting in just *don't*

So my logic (which I'm sure could be improved) was to have two while loops, one starting at the end and one at the beginning, traversing and erasing until it hits a non-punctuation char.

```
void stripPunct(string & str) {
    string::iterator itr1 = str.begin();
    string::reverse_iterator itr2 = str.rbegin();

    while ( ispunct(*itr1) ) {
        str.erase(itr1);
        itr1++;
    }

    while ( ispunct(*itr2) ) {
        str.erase(itr2);
        itr2--;
    }
}
```

However, obviously it's not working because erase() requires a regular iterator and not a reverse_iterator. But anyways, I feel like that logic is pretty inefficient.

Also, I tried instead of a reverse_iterator using just a regular iterator, starting it at str.end(), then decremented it, but it says I cannot dereference the iterator if I start it at str.end().

Can anyone help me with a good way to do this? Or maybe point out a workaround for what I already have?

Thank you so much in advance!

------------------ [ EDIT ] ----------------------------

found a solution, although it may not be the best solution:

```
// Call the stripPunct method:

stripPunct(str);
if ( !str.empty() ) { // make sure string is still valid
  // perform other code
}
```

And here is the stripPunct method:

```
void stripPunct(string & str) {
   string::iterator itr1 = str.begin();
   string::iterator itr2 = str.end();

   while ( !(str.empty()) && ispunct(*itr1) ) 
       itr1 = str.erase(itr1);

   itr2--;
   if ( itr2 != str.begin() ) {

       while ( !(str.empty()) && ispunct(*itr2) ) {
           itr2 = str.erase(itr2);
           itr2--;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: What you're surely doing wrong is that you're using `itr1` and `itr2` after you've erased them, you should replace them with the value returned by `erase`.

Comment: Forgot about that, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 4):

First, note a couple problems with your code:

- after you call `erase()` using `itr1`, you've invalidated `itr2`.
- when using a `reverse_iterator` to go backwards through a sequence, you want to use `++`, not `--` (that's kind of the reason reverse iterators exist).

Now, to improve the logic, you can avoid erasing each character individually by finding the first charater you *don't* want to erase and erase everything up to that point.  `find_if()` can be used to help with that:

```
int not_punct(char c) {
    return !ispunct((unsigned char) c);
}

void stripPunct(string & str) {
    string::iterator itr = find_if( str.begin(), str.end(), not_punct);

    str.erase( str.begin(), itr);

    string::reverse_iterator ritr = find_if( str.rbegin(), str.rend(), not_punct);

    str.erase( ritr.base(), str.end());
}
```

Note that I've used `base()` to get the 'regular' iterator corresponding to the `reverse_iterator`.  I find the logic for whether `base()` needs to be adjusted confusing (reverse iterators in general confuse me)- in this case it doesn't because we happen to want to start the erase after the character that's found.

This article by Scott Meyers, http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184401406, has a good treatment of `reverse_iterator::base()` in the section. "Guideline 3: Understand How to Use a reverse_iterator's Base iterator".  The information in that article has also been incorporated into Meyer's "Effective STL" book.

Comment: Michael, thank you that looks useful and the better way of doing things. Will look into that. I also posted a sloppy solution I came up with in my original question.

Comment: @Rhinoo: note that I got rid of the `if` tests after the `find_if()`: they're unnecessary and in fact will prevent a string that contains only punctuation from being trimmed to the empty string.

Comment: Also note that instead of coming up with a little wrapper function to pass to `find_if()` you can be more STL-like and use the function object helpers from header `<functional>`:  instead of `not_punct` pass in `not1(ptr_fun<int, int>(ispunct))`  However, I frankly find that kind of thing less readable more often than not.

Answer (score 0):

You can't dereference iterator::end() because it points to invalid memory (memory right after the end of the array), so you have to decrement it first.

And one final note: if the word consists only of punctuations, your program will fail, be sure to handle that.

Comment: First, yes I know, I decrement it first, my compiler (visual studio 2010) still gives me that error. Sorry I should have specified that in my question. Secondly, I do handle the error case, just didn't put it in the code in my question.

Comment: I think I got that error because of what Matteo Italia said above, I forgot to reassign the iterators.

Comment: Nope, it still gives me the "string iterator not dereferencable" for itr2 if I use a regular iterator, set it to str.end() and then decrement it first.

Comment: I'll look into it tomorrow again, apparently I am too sleepy to think properly.

Comment: Erbureth, thanks for helping me at all. And actually, it wasn't that. Somewhere I'm not handling an error case, but it does work for some strings. Thank you again!

Comment: You cannot decrement end() (even if it makes sense, the VS lib's iterator checks will fail). A pass by is (++string.rbegin()).base().

Comment: I'm confused - it's perfectly valid to decrement the iterator returned by `end()` if the container isn't empty (for `std::string` or other objects that return bi-directional iterators).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind negative logic, you can do the following:

```
string tmp_str="";
tmp_str.reserve(str.length());
for (string::iterator itr1 = str.begin(); itr1 != str.end(); itr1++)
{
   if (!ispunct(*itr1))
   {
      tmp_str.push_back(*itr1);
   }
}
str = tmp_str;
```